# TensorFlow learn.Estimator : is it naive to call fit() many times? Because I get ResourceExhaustedError

Tags: loops, tensorflow

I am learning machine learning using TensorFlow. I have been through a couple of tutorials but I still have a hard time trying to find what are the good ways of training a model. Recently I implemented a CNN model I found in the litterature. The model must take a crop of a certain size centered on a given pixel and predict the label of this pixel. It does that for each pixel of the image. I used:

```
classifier = tf.learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="./cnn")
```

with cnn_model_fn beeing a function I implemented.

For each training image, we take 3000 crops randomly, so I can't load all theses images and their crops to memory. The way I found is by loading one image at a time, extract the 3000 crops and then call classifier.fit() to train on the 3000 crops. Then loop for each image in my dataset.

```
for i in range(len(filenames)):
    ...
    image = misc.imread(filenames[i])
    labels = misc.imread(groundTruth[i]) #labels for each pixels

    input_classifier = preprocess(image,...) #crops 3000 images in  image and do other things
    input_labels = preprocess_labels(labels, ...) #take the corresponding 3000 labels

    classifier.fit(x = input_classifier,
                   y = input_labels,
                   batch_size = 30
                   steps = 100)
```

It worked fine for 100 images, but if I try on the whole dataset (2000 images), it always stops and give an error of ResourceExhausted.

```
...
[everything goes well]
...
iteration :227/2000
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating 
TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus 
id: 0000:01:00.0)
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating 
TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus 
id: 0000:01:00.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train-cnn.py", line 78, in <module>
classifier.fit(x= input_classifier, y=input_labels,batch_size=30, steps=100)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 280, in new_func
...
... 
...
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: cnn/graph.pbtxt.tmp32bcc6311c164c29b91177d17d05d669
```

I don't see why it gets OOM... I have suspicions that it is because of the way I call fit() in loop. After each fit(), a ckpt is saved and it must be restored right after to train on the next image. So is it a bad way to train a model?

Answer (score 0):

running estimator.fit in a loop with smaller steps is not a good idea. I would put all input logic into an input_fn. then run estimator.fit only once with more steps.
An example of reading data from different files can be found here: `tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_examples`